# When does Regularisation term make sense?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, deep-learning, regularization

Suppose that we have a network which performs poorly on the **training** set, something like ~40% accuracy.

Does it make any sense at all to add a regularisation term in such case? Isn't it only needed when overfitting occurs?

Comment: I think you need to describe the problem in more detail.

Comment: If you can only reach 40% accuracy on your training set, it seems like something is wrong with either your model or the optimization procedure, hence overfitting won't be the first of your concerns.

Comment: @galoosh33 it's not a problem actually, the model is pretty simple for this problem that's why the low accuracy. The question is more theoretical.

Comment: @MichaelChernick The question is more theoretical, that is, I have a simple model that performs ~40% on training set. The thing is that by adding more and more regularisation there is actually no gains on the test set. The accuracy is always less on all sets (train/val/test).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't tell from your model's performance on the training data whether you have overfit. Even your "poor" accuracy of 40% may be due to overfitting and may not generalize. You can't tell *a priori* what is poor and what isn't. So you might indeed be able to improve your out-of-sample accuracy through regularization.

I'd suggest you partition your data. Fit your model on 75%. Record your in-sample accuracy on these 75%, as well as the out-of-sample accuracy on the remaining 25%. Do this multiple times with different randomly sampled 75%. Your out-of-sample accuracy will usually be lower than in-sample, but if it is often "much" lower, that might be an indicator of overfitting. ("much" is not easily quantified.) In such a case, regularization might be helpful.

Comment: I don't see how overfitting on training set will reduce training set accuracy.

Comment: I didn't claim that. Overfitting might reduce out-of-sample accuracy.